# ScrollViewer position in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, scrollviewer

Is it possible to assign a value to a ScrollViewer in XAML by data-binding? I have a collection of objects (tabs) which are added dynamicaly. Whenever I add a new tab the scrollviewer position should go to the end but it doesn't. I don't want to set the position to be precise, just align the bar position to the very right. Thanks.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                            <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                              Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Margin="2,2,2,0"
                              IsItemsHost="true"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
```

Comment: HorizontalContentAlignment="Right", HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Align}" i don't know what else to try

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.